# PyCharm не идентифицирует модуль math

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.6

При написании `import math` PyCharm подводит math красной линией и при наведении курсора на него выдаёт *No module named math*. Сам math работает, т.е. при выполнении кода

```
import math
print(math.pi)
```

Получаю заветные 3,14...

Однако PyCharm этот модуль не распознаёт и в External Libraries его нет.
Как сделать так, чтобы PyCharm снова его "увидел"?

Comment: Как обнаружили-то?

Comment: Попробовал импортировать его, на что пайчарм сообщил, что нету модуля с таким именем

Comment: Всего лишь пайчарм подчеркнул или код вообще никак не запускается с ошибкой?

Comment: Только пайчарм, странно, в начале проверял - выдавало ошибку ссылаясь на модуль. Уже не критично, но всё равно интересно почему пайчарм его не видит

Comment: похоже [проблема с самим PyCharm](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203368550/comments/115000636590). Попробуйте 1- закрыть/открыть 2- убедиться, что настройки для исполняемого файла (/usr/bin/python), virtualenv, PYTHONPATH разумные в pycharm 3- попробовать обновить pycharm. Для теста свежую инсталляцию, с нуля запустить.

Comment: @jfs Всё нормализировалось, снёс старую версию, поставил новую, благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос задан давно. Разработчики PyCharm решили эту проблему и в новой версии этой ошибки нет.