# No module named 'requests'

Tags: python

Модуль `requests` устанавливал через

```console
pip install requests
```

В файле `.py` ругается на `import requests`

> No module named 'requests'

Может в папку с проектом нужно какие-то файлы добавлять?

Comment: В папку ничего добавлять не надо. Какая у вас версия Python? Какая OS? Приведите свой тестовый код.

Comment: В среде Thonny работает прекрасно, в IDLE - не работает

Comment: Возможно стоит попробовать переустановить среду, у меня была аналогичная ситуация с пайчармом, помогло. Смотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783517/pycharm-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c-math)

Answer (score 1):

Настоятельно рекомендую уйти от глобальности установки пакетов и воспользоваться виртуальным пространством. [Здесь ответ с описанием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1335729/209304) различных решений для этого дела. И вот вам практическое применение, все команды вводятся из папки, которая есть корень проекта

```sh
% python3 -m venv env
% . env/bin/activate
(env) % python -m pip install --upgrade pip
(env) % python -m pip install requests
```