# В чем разница между venv и virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, venv

1. `venv`, это встроенный инструмент, `virtualenv` нужно отдельно устанавливать
2. `venv` создает окружение дольше, чем `virtualenv`

Есть ли еще разница? (русскоязычных тем по этому вопросу не нашел)

Comment: Кто-нибудь может перевести англоязычную тему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587

Comment: ассоциация:stackoverflow.com/q/41573587/10562663

Answer (score 9):

Перевод с enSO [самый оценный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41573588/10562663) с последними правками от 27.06.2021 (автор [Flimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247696/flimm))

#### Персональные рекомендации автора оригинального ответа для новичков

Это персональная рекомендация от автора ответа: начните обучение с [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) и [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) - инструменты, которые работают с обеими версиями Python 2 и 3 и в различных ситуациях и беритесь за другие, как только они вам понадобятся.

## PyPI модули нестандартной библиотеки

- **[`virtualenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)** очень популярный инструмент для создания изолированного окружения для Python библиотек. Если вы еще не знакомы с данным иснтрументом, то я вам настоятельно рекомендую изучить его. Я буду сравнивать с данным инструментом до конца ответа.

Это работает как установка группы файлов в директорию (например: `env/`), а затем модифицируется переменная среды `PATH` добавлением к ней префикса пользовательской директории `bin` (например: `env/bin/`). Точная копия бинарников `python` или `python3` распологается в данной директории и Python запрограммирован так, что сначала ищет библиотеки относительно данного пути, в директории окружения. Данный инструмент не является частью стандартной библиотеки Python, но официально благославлена [PyPa  (Python Packaging Authority)](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/). Единожды активировав, вы можете устанавливать пакеты в виртуальное пространство, используя `pip`.

- **[`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)** используется для изолирования версий python. К примеру, вы хотели бы протестировать ваш код на Python 2.7, 3.6, 3.7 и 3.8, тогда вам бы понадобилось решение для переключения между ними. После активации, к переменной окружения `PATH` добавляется `~/.pyenv/shims`, где находятся специальные файлы сопоставления команд Python (`python`, `pip`). Это не копии команд, поставляемых с Python, а специальные скрипты, которые на лету решают какую версию Python запустить, основываясь на `PYENV_VERSION`-переменной среды, либо на `.python-version`-файле, либо `~/.pyenv/version` файле. `pyenv` так же облегчает процессы скачивания и установки нескольких версий Python при использовании команды `pyenv install`.
- **[`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv)** является плагином для `pyenv`, от того же автора что и `pyenv` и позволяет удобно использовать `pyenv` и `virtualenv` одновременно. Однако, если вы используете Python 3.3 или выше, то  `pyenv-virtualenv` будет пробовать запускать `python -m venv`, если таковое доступно, иначе `virtualenv`. Вы можете использовать `virtualenv` и `pyenv` вместе, без `pyenv-virtualenv`, если вы не нуждаетесь в удобном функционале.
- **[`virtualenvwrapper`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper)** - это набор расширений к `virtualenv` (см. [документацию](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). У вас появляются такие команды, как `mkvirtualenv`, `lssitepackages` и особенно `workon` для переключения между различными каталогами `virtualenv`.Этот инструмент особенно полезен, если вам нужно несколько каталогов `virtualenv`.
- **[`pyenv-virtualenvwrapper`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper)** - это плагин для `pyenv` того же автора, для удобной интеграции `virtualenvwrapper` в `pyenv`.
- **[`pipenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipenv)** - стремление объеденить `Pipfile`, `pip` и `virtualenv` в одну команду в командной строке. Каталог `virtualenv` обычно помещается в `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/XXX`, где `XXX` является хешем пути к каталогу проекта. Это отличает данный инструмент от `virtualenv`, где директория обычно расположена в папке с проектом. `pipenv` предназначен для использования при разработке приложений Python (в отличие от библиотек). Существуют альтернативы `pipenv`, такие как [`poetry`](https://pypi.org/project/poetry/), которые я не буду здесь перечислять, поскольку этот вопрос касается только пакетов с аналогичными названиями.

## Стандартные библиотеки

- **`pyvenv`** (не путать с **[`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)** из предыдущей части) - это скрипт, поставляемый с Python 3, версиях с 3.3 по 3.7, но [устарел в Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.6.html#id8) и был удален из Python 3.8, поскольку имелись проблемы (не говоря уж о сбивающем с толку названии). В Python 3.6+, точный эквивалент - `python3 -m venv`.
- **[`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)** - это пакет поставляемый с Python 3, который вы можете запустить с помощью `python3 -m venv` (хотя по некоторым причинам некоторые дистрибутивы выделяют его в отдельный пакет, такие как `python3-venv` в Ubuntu/Debian). Он служит той же цели, что и `virtualenv`, но имеет только подмножество его функций ([см. Сравнение здесь](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)). `virtualenv` по-прежнему более популярен, чем `venv`, тем более что первый поддерживает как Python 2, так и 3.