# При активации виртуалики(venv) пишет, что нет таких-то модулей. pip install -r req.txt(пример) тулит все в папку, где находиться сам python. windows10

Tags: pip

Не хочется захламлять основной python(где он установлен). Может в последствии и не пригодиться. Вопрос: как поднять модули не цепляя основной папки, где установлен python. Или неизбежно? Не поймите меня, неправильно. Если, я загрузил код, загрузил модули, они остались у меня в основной папке. Нах.. а тогда venv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Избежно. `venv` для таких случаев и существует.

Алгоритм такой (все команды под CMD):

1. Устанавливаете `venv` ([вот здесь я писал возможные версии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1335729/209304)) и как это работает.
   Для windows в самом широком смысле

```
C:\project>py -m venv env
```

На данном этапе у вас в папке `C:\project` появится папка `.env`, которая будет содержать собственный python и зависимости. Которые при установке будут появляться здесь `.env\Lib\site-packages\`

2. Активируете

```
C:\project>env\Scripts\activate
```

в командной строке вы должны увидеть что такое

```
(env) C:\project
```

3. И ради интереса спросить установленные модули на данный момент

```
(env) C:\project>pip freeze
```

Если сделали все правильно, то ничего не будет выведено. То есть никаких сторонних модулей под данным виртуальным пространством нет

4. А вот теперь если у вас есть файл с зависимостями, то можно запустить

```
(env) C:\project>pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Или для проверки установить модуль например с `requests`

```
(env) C:\project>pip install requests
```

И если вы выполните команду

```
(env) C:\project>pip freeze
```

то увидите сторонние модули установленные только что с версиями.

Я, субъективно, отвергаю любую возможность работать в глобальном пространстве. И любой проект у меня сопровождается обязательно виртуальным пространством и файлами с зависимостями (requirements.txt), для разных надобностей разные. Например, я разделяю для разработки (dev-requirements.txt), для тестирования (test-requirements.txt) и для прода (prod-requirements.txt)

Comment: Все так и делаю. Когда просто откриваю cmd пишу pip freeze, ответ: пустая строка.  После активации проекта и запуска pip install -r requirements.txt, идет запуск. При откритии нового окна cmd, уже они существуют.  pip - V, пишет, что установленно в ОСНОВНУЮ ПАПКУ. Где лежит сам python.

Comment: Хотя в проете в /Lib/site-packages они все спокойно лежат

Comment: Как вы понимаете где у вас установлены модули? Есть ли у вас папка env в проекте?

Comment: Если лежат, значит они в виртуальном пространстве

Comment: Но при запуске .py файла, пишет, что нет

Comment: pyvenv.cfg находит правильно путь. Установлен python3.10.1

Comment: Запускайте файл под виртуальным пространством `(env) C:\project>py your_file.py`

Comment: Спасибо, немного отошли от теми. Я просто хочу разобраться, почему из виртулального окружения, установка етих же пакетов(requests, bs4, speech_recognition) через requirements.txt ставит их в общюю папку python/ Пример: сам проект E:/clock/(тут виртуалка 'Lib, Scripts, Include'), после установки все оказивается в B:/install/python3.10/ , основная папка)

Comment: Кстати, такое же и при скачивании с git`а