# Помогите с модулем pytube пожалуйста

Tags: python, установка, pytube

Установил модуль pytube, а он отказывает импортироваться, другие модули нормально работают.
Может ли это быть из-за винды? Хотя на своем основном компьютере, где 10-ка, все равно эта проблема.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `pip freeze` что выдает в консоли?

Comment: colorama ==0.4.4 \
pygame==2.1.2 \
pytube==12.1.0

Comment: То есть в pytube модуля нет.  Тогда исправьте сам вопрос описанием как вы устанавливаете, используете ли виртуальное окружение, каким установщик пакетов пользуетесь

Comment: Комментарий обновил, все библиотеки которые я устанавливал есть

Comment: Тогда в этой же командной строке запустите интерпетатор питона и импортируйте библиотеку. Получилось?

Comment: Странно, там все заработало. С чем это может быть связано, не подскажете?)

Comment: разные питоны и/или окружения.

Comment: Вот здесь ответ как работать с вирт окружением [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1370218/209304). Возьмите за правило под каждый проект иметь свое окружение со своими версиями питона и установленными модулями. Ести тот ответ поможет, не забудьте его оценить. А [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1335729/209304) описание разных утилит для виртаульных окружений, как пользоваться и ссылки на документации

Comment: Окружения - это IDE?

Comment: И да, можно немного подробнее, зачем под каждый проект использовать разные версии Python и разными модулями?

Comment: Нет, IDE - это интегрированая среда разработки, виртуальное пространство - это пространство в котором может быть определенная версия питона и набор модулей и библиотек. IDE типа PyCharm позволяют управлять виртуальным пространством. Зачем? Чтобы не было таких конфликтов как у вас, создание различных пространств под разработку/тестирование/деплой, позволяет переносить пространство с сохранением всех версий и зависимостей. И самый главный плюс - основное пространство не загажено и там не стоит куча всяких модулей, в которых поддчас невозможно разобраться

Comment: IMHO пользуйтесь сразу хорошими IDE типа PyCharm или Visual studio code. Они мощные, но из коробки имеют все, что надо начинающим. А с опытом разберетесь и прочувствуете все плюсы их мощности

Comment: Не уверен, что моя машина вывезет PyCharm. Насчет VSC не знаю, попробую. Спасибо большое, очень выручили!

Comment: Тогда [atom](https://atom.io/) попробуйте, он полегче. Это все мнения и снимаю с себя всякую ответственность =)

Comment: Хорошо. Я качал его, не разобрался и удалил))). Опять установлю и точно разберусь.
Как оценить комментарий, подскажите пожалуйста)

Comment: Только ответы оцениваются, которые вам помогли и оказали помощь, оценивайте и вопрос и ответ, который вы используете. Комментарии не имеют никакой ценности

Comment: Извините, я постараюсь разобраться. Спасибо )