# Python. Создание виртуального окружения с другой версией Python

Tags: python, virtualenv

Операционная система Windows 10. Интерпретатор python 3.9.5
Как я могу создать виртуальное окружение, к примеру с python 3.6?
Пробовал и через mkvirtualenv, не получилось(
Как сделать это на Windows и Linux. Спасибо!

Comment: Для начала установить интерпретатор версии 3.6

Comment: Под Windows можно через утилиту py: `py -3.6 -m venv .venv`

Answer (score 1):

Для Windows.

1. Установите ту версию python, которую хотите использовать в
   виртуальном пространстве. ВАЖНО! Если у вас есть основаная версия и вы не хотите конфликтов, то на моменте установки снимите галочку с опции `Add python 3.6 to PATH`
2. Далее введите (при условии, что у вас установлен python)

```
py -3.6 -m venv env
```

И вы получите виртуально пространство с python 3.6, которое будет лежать в папке `env`

Оговорки:

Если вы не установите нужную версию перед созданием пространства, то получите такое сообщение

```
Python 3.6 not found!
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64 *
 -3.8-64

Requested Python version (3.6) not installed, use -0 for available pythons
```

Про возможности и обзор на различные утилиты можете найти в [моем ответе здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1335729/209304). В том числе там сможете найти краткое описание и ссылки на `pyenv`

Answer (score 1):

У меня к сожалению не Windows, но на MacOS это работает так:

1. Установить в систему (не как основной, а просто скачать и запустить установщик) python нужной версии
2. в консоли заходите в папку в которой хотите создать виртуальное окружение python.
3. пишите команду `python3.x -m venv name` (вместо `x` пишите номер версии питона после точки, а вместо `name` пишите название вашего окружения)
4. Ну вот и все! в моей системе это все что надо для создания `venv`! для активации просто написать команду `source name/bin/activate`.
   Надеюсь я вам как-то помог!

Comment: В linux пишет что bash: python3.10.2: command not found.
python3-venv стоит.
В windows ориентировочно понял как сделать: 
1.Скачиваешь желаемую версию, устанавливаешь в определенную папку без отметки PATH
2.Через cmd заходишь папку где установил последнею версию
3.И запускаешь venv от той версии, который хочешь, в принципе всё работает!

Минус в том,что это костыль и как то неграмтно. Возможно комментарий снизу укажут на правду, используя pynev, но пока не проверял.

Comment: все просто потому, что надо писать в вашем случае ```python3.10``` без ```.2```, и еще можно написать ```python3.``` несколько раз  нажать Tab и у вас должны высветиться варианты что можно написать, выбираете из предложенного то что вам нужно, и пишите

Answer (score 0):

Для такой задачи вполне себе подойдет pyenv

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Также не плохая статья по поводу pyenv

https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/