# Пытаюсь установить pyautogui и keyboard, но мне выдает ошибку:

Tags: python, pip

При установке пакетов `pyautogui` и `keyboard` получаю ошибку:

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

P.s. Стоит OS X 10.13.6

Comment: Оно пишет, что Питон 2.7 больше не поддерживается. Используйте 3-й питон.

Comment: Я попытался установить 3-й питон, но не вышло.  Возможно, я делать, что-то не так.

Comment: Ну показывайте - что именно не вышло. Так вам не помогут без симптомов

Comment: MBP-Kusakabe:~ Abramich$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
MBP-Kusakabe:~ Abramich$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.2. Если я не ошибаюсь, то 3-й питон уже установлен, но ошибка все равно вылезает.

Comment: Пробовали устанавливать библиотеки через `pip3`, чтобы они точно в 3-й питон ставились?

Comment: Пробовал, но ничего не вышло. Не исключено, что я делал, что-то не так.

Comment: "Ничего не вышло" - это ни о чём. Всё что пробовали и какие ошибки при этом вышли - добавляйте в вопрос, вы можете его редактировать.

Answer (score 1):

у тебя python 2 поэтому pip не  хочет скачивать эти библиотеки обнови python до 3 версии (python-3x)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работает на POSIX операционных системах, включая macOS, то могу рекомендовать не использовать команды `pip/pip3` на прямую, а всегда указывать интерпретатор `python`. И в первую очередь необходимо уточнить установлен ли `python` той версии с которой вы собираетесь работать

Для 3 версии на macOS

узнать версию

```console
python3 -V
```

установить через `pip`

```console
python3 -m pip install <package_name>
```

Или можно указать абсолютный путь до интерпретатора python

```console
path/to/your/python -V
path/to/your/python -m pip install <package_name>
```

Настоятельно рекомендую уйти от глобальности установки пакетов и воспользоваться виртуальным пространством. [Здесь ответ с описанием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1335729/209304) различных решений для этого дела. И вот вам практическое применение, все команды вводятся из папки, которая есть корень проекта

```sh
% python3 -m venv env
% . env/bin/activate
(env) % python -m pip install --upgrade pip
(env) % python -m pip install pyautogui
(env) % python -m pip install keyboard
```