# Kali Linux: Ошибка при установке NetfilterQueue

Tags: python-3.x, kali-linux

При вводе

```bash
apt-get install build-essential python-dev libnetfilter-queue-dev
```

Вот что выдает

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
    python2-dev python2 python-dev-is-python3

E: Package 'python-dev' has no installation candidate
```

При

```bash
pip install NetfilterQueue
```

выдает

```
Collecting NetfilterQueue
    Using cached NetfilterQueue-1.0.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
    Installing build dependencies ... done
    Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: NetfilterQueue
    Building wheel for NetfilterQueue (pyproject.toml) ... error
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × Building wheel for NetfilterQueue (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [30 lines of output]
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/netfilterqueue
        copying netfilterqueue/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/netfilterqueue
        copying netfilterqueue/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/netfilterqueue
        running egg_info
        writing NetfilterQueue.egg-info/PKG-INFO
        writing dependency_links to NetfilterQueue.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
        writing top-level names to NetfilterQueue.egg-info/top_level.txt
        reading manifest file 'NetfilterQueue.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
        adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
        writing manifest file 'NetfilterQueue.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        copying netfilterqueue/_impl.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/netfilterqueue
        copying netfilterqueue/_impl.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/netfilterqueue
        copying netfilterqueue/_impl.pyx -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/netfilterqueue
        copying netfilterqueue/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/netfilterqueue
        running build_ext
        building 'netfilterqueue._impl' extension
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/netfilterqueue
        x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c netfilterqueue/_impl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/netfilterqueue/_impl.o
        netfilterqueue/_impl.c:718:10: fatal error: libnfnetlink/linux_nfnetlink.h: No such file or directory
        718 | #include "libnfnetlink/linux_nfnetlink.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        compilation terminated.
        error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
        [end of output]
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for NetfilterQueue
Failed to build NetfilterQueue                                                                           
ERROR: Could not build wheels for NetfilterQueue, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Версия python: 3.9.10
Я читал, что это возможно из-за версии и нужно ее понизить.
Как понизить - не нашел.

Comment: Когда пытался понизить версию, то выдавало ошибку: warning: running pip as root will break packages and permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На счет первой ошибки. Вот [лог поддержки](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/4151#issuecomment-519116786) и [описание](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/No_more_-dev_packages), что `python-dev` больше не существует и не поддерживается. Вместо этого используется `python`

На счет второй ошибки. Попробуйте не использовать глобальный `pip/pip3`. Используйте явное указание интерпретатора `python`

```bash
python3 -m pip install <package_name>
```

А лучше всего использовать виртуальное окружение и работать в нем [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Попробуйте также установку из исходников `git`

```bash
python3 -m pip install cython
git clone https://github.com/oremanj/python-netfilterqueue
cd python-netfilterqueue
python3 -m pip install .
```

Comment: Вторая ошибка так и не решилась:   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for NetfilterQueue
Failed to build NetfilterQueue                                                                          
ERROR: Could not build wheels for NetfilterQueue, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects  

Написал так, как вы - python3 -m pip install NetfilterQueue

Comment: @wunogradsky вы же так и не воспользовались виртуальным окружением. Я прав? Если это так, то настоятельно рекомендую

Comment: да, я еще не знаком с ним. и об этом как раз говорит warning при cython: WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv   
где я могу почитать об этом?

Comment: @wunogradsky вот [я писал ответ об этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1335729/209304). Не забывайте оценивать ответы, которые вам полезны

Comment: @wunogradsky [Вот коротко](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1410221/209304), чтобы быстро начать

Comment: Спасибо. При установке virtualenv так же выдает ошибку, о которой я написал выше: WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

Comment: @wunogradsky уйдите из под `root` пользователя.

Comment: @wunogradsky теперь ваш рейтинг позволяет голосовать "за" и отмечать полезные вопросы/ответы

Comment: Вижу. Спасибо вам. Проголосовал за ваш ответ в вашей теме про venv. Попробовал exit и CTRL+D, не получилось выйти из root. Скорее это потому что пользователь root, а самих прав нет, раз ошибка

Comment: @wunogradsky для того, чтобы разрешить вопрос не связанный с проблемой в самом вопросе, могу рекомендовать задать новый вопрос или поискать уже готовый ответ. Комментарии для такой деятельности не подходят. Модель здесь такая: конкретный вопрос -> конкретный ответ. Все остальное офтоп